# Como passar, via AJAX, múltiplos formulários com múltiplos arquivos

Tags: php, ajax

Possuo 3 formulários numa mesma página, onde cada formulário tem inputs do tipo arquivo. Necessito que ao clicar em um único botão, seja possível encaminhar, utilizando Ajax, corretamente todos os campos (principalmente que $_FILES fique disponível na página PHP).

Tentei o seguinte:

```
$('#cadastrar-emp').on('click', function () {
    var form = $('#formCadEmp')[0],
        formII = $('#formConfNFe')[0],
        formIII = $('#formConfEmail')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form),
        dataII = new FormData(formII),
        dataIII = new FormData(formIII);

    data.append('formConfNFe', JSON.stringify(dataII));
    data.append('formConfEmail', JSON.stringify(dataIII));
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "actions/cadastrar-empresa.php",
        type: 'post',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {}
    });
});
```

E obtive na página PHP:

```
Array
(
    [razao-social] => 
    [nome-fantasia] => 
    [cnpj] => 
    [estado] => 
    [cep] => 
    [cidade] => 
    [logradouro] => 
    [bairro] => 
    [complemento] => 
    [numero] => 
    [email] => 
    [celular] => 
    [fixo] => 
    [insc-estadual] => 
    [insc-municipal] => 
    [cnae-fiscal] => 
    [reg-trib] => 1
    [formConfNFe] => {}
    [formConfEmail] => {}
)
```

Sendo que dessa forma, não consigo acessar as propriedades do *array* `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que você não está pegando os arquivos via Ajax para serem enviados.

A maneira correta de recuperá-los é assim:

```
var formCadEmp = $('#formCadEmp').prop('files')[0];
```

Ou seja, você carrega todos os arquivos nas variaveis e cria somente um FormData e utiliza a função append para adicionar toda a informação que você quer que chegue no seu PHP.

Eu tentaria desta forma:

```
var formCadEmp    = $('#formCadEmp').prop('files')[0];
var formConfNFe   = $('#formConfNFe').prop('files')[0];
var formConfEmail = $('#formConfEmail').prop('files')[0];
var dadosForm     = $('#form').serialize();

var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('formCadEmp', formCadEmp);
form_data.append('formConfNFe', formCadEmp);
form_data.append('formConfEmail', formCadEmp);
form_data.append('dadosForm', dadosForm);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){}       
});
```

No seu PHP, os arquivos files ficariam dentros das chaves formCadEmp, formConfNFe e formConfEmail do array $_POST.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá @BrunoFoller: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: Desculpa. `$('#formCadEmp').prop('files')[0];` é o id do campo que recebe o file.